# SSAS Cube - sub-group measures

Tags: ssas

I am creating a SSAS cube and have measures from an account fact table. Is it possible to group those further into sub-groups?

I am looking at rather than having a list of 20 measures having 4 groups of 5 measures to make it easier for users by having them logically grouped.

I could create 4 separate views to make them appear in their own groups, but I really want them all under the same group since they are all balances.

I guess I have the same question on dimensions.  Does a SSAS cube just not support any groupings below the dimension/measure level?

Comment: So, it looks like I am looking for the DisplayFolder property for measures. I haven't found a way to do it for dimension  attributes though.

Comment: yes, try the DisplayFolder property. For dimension attributes see the AttributeHierarchyDisplayFolder property